# How should I wire in Spring 4.2 ApplicationEventPublisher with out using autowire using xml constructor arg?

Tags: spring, events

I see there are lots of implementations, but how do I use the default implementation without using autowire and using xml config?

Comment: I want to avoid having to use the interface everywhere I need a publisher. My goal is to just wire in the publisher though the constructor are of my beans. I just don't know what to wire in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several option, you can use annotations, implement and interface or explicitly declare the dependency in xml or java config.

To get the [`ApplicationEventPublisher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisher.html) you can implement the [`ApplicationEventPublisherAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisherAware.html) and implement the method, the `ApplicationContext` knows about this interface and will call the setter to give you the `ApplicationEventPublisher`.

```
public SomeClass implementens ApplicationEventPublisherAware {
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        this.publisher= applicationEventPublisher;
    }
}
```

With annotation you can just put `@Autowired` on the field

```
public SomeClass implementens ApplicationEventPublisherAware {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
}
```

If it is a required dependency I would suggest using constructor injection, added benefit (IMHO) is that you can make the field `final` and that you cannot construct an invalid instance.

```
public SomeClass implementens ApplicationEventPublisherAware {
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Autowired
    public SomeClass(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        this.publisher= applicationEventPublisher;
    }
```

When using Java Config you can simply create a `@Bean` annotated method which takes an `ApplicationEventPublisher` as argument.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SomeClass someClass(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        return new SomeClass(applicationEventPublisher);
    }
}
```

For XML you would need to autowire the constructor, you can specify this on the specific bean element.

```
<bean id="someId" class="SomeClass" autowire="constructor" />
```

Comment: Something like applicationEventMulticaster is exactly what I am looking for. When I wire that in I get the following: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster] to required type [org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher]:

Comment: Doh. Sorry my bad, that isn't going to work. I removed that part of the answer, in Java Config it is pretty easy, it will also work in xml if you autowire the constructor.

Comment: The problem is I am using xml config and I can't use autowired :(. If worse comes to worse, I can just add the interface, but I would like to avoid that. What is the actual implementation that gets autowired in? It seems odd to me that I can't just reference the same bean that autowired puts in. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Have you seen my last edit? Why wouldn't you be able to autowire the constructor for a single bean?

Comment: If all else fails, yes, I could do that. The goal is to not have to autowire it in and to be able to specify it through the xml context configuration.

Comment: Well you cannot do that with XML, you could, as pointed, do that with Java Config but not with XML. For that either use auto wiring or implement the said interface.

Comment: When you are "@Autowiring" ApplicationEventPublisher, you don't need to do "implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware"